# how can get a field with label as date in php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$count = 1;

foreach($_SESSION["searchmultipleTSIKDO"] as $key=>$rows) {

    echo '<tr><td>'.$count++.'.</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rows["key"].'</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    if ( $rows["key"] == 'bcounty') {
        $array = $listcounty->get("WHERE id = $rows[value]");
        foreach($array as $rows1) {
            echo $rows1["name"];
        }
    } 
    else if ( $rows["key"] == 'gender') {
        if ( $rows["value"] == 1) {
            echo 'Male';
        } else {
            echo 'Female';
        }
    } 
    else if ( $rows["key"] == 'dob') {
        .......
        }   
    }
    else if ( $rows["key"] == 'qualification') {
        $array = $listqualification->get("WHERE id = $rows[value]");
        foreach($array as $rows1) {
            echo $rows1["name"];
        }   
    }
    else {
        echo $rows["value"];
    }
    echo '</td>';
    echo "<td><a href=\"report.php?deletesearchmultiple=$key\" style='color: red;'> X</a></td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is the question here?

Comment: @u_mulder I think OP want the code that code here: `else if ( $rows["key"] == 'dob') {
        .......
        } `

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
else if ( $rows["key"] == 'dob') {
  echo '<label>DOB: <input type="date" value="'.date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",$rows["value"]).'" /></label>';
}
```

Comment: Label is already there, when i chose the dob label, i need to have option to select the date.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. There is no label on your code where you have .......

Comment: Please provide only relevant code and show an example of expected output - it is now completely unclear what you want

Comment: echo "<select name='key' onchange=\"keyvalue(this.value); return false;\">";
echo '<option>Select field</option>';
 foreach($rows as $key=>$value) {
   if ( $key != 'id' && $key != 'registerdate' && $key != 'enteredby' && $key != 'bcountry' && $key != 'btown' && $key != 'image' && $key != 'category') {
    echo "<option>$key</option>";
   }
  }
  echo '</select>';

Comment: Mr mplungjan, Thank you for your reply. I am new to stackoverflow community. so i cant put more than one question for today. Above is the code for label selection.

Comment: Please update existing code instead of posting code in a comment - it is still not clear what you want.